# Picklist field is disabled in LWC Datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, picklist, datatable

I have a picklist field which I am fetching data from Apex. Now the scenario is I have to fetch all the data and I'm able to see those values in console.log but the picklist field looks greyed out and not able to edit even after adding wrapText=true. I created custom type for picklist.
The values are not visible. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Please help me on this.

[image: Image for Reference]

[image: Console log:]
Here is my code:

**aRADataTable.html:**

```
    <c-custom-type-global
    data={dataRecords}
    columns={columns} 
    key-field="Id" 
    suppress-bottom-bar
    oncellchange={handleSave} 
    draft-values={saveDraftValues} 
    errors={errors} 
    wrap-text-max-lines=3
    hide-checkbox-column 
    horizontal-scroll-hidden
    onkeyup={changeInTable}>
</c-custom-type-global>
    </lightning-card>
```

**aRADataTable.js:**

```
import { LightningElement, track,api } from 'lwc';
import fetchInventoryDataTableRecords from 
'@salesforce/apex/ARAInventoryTypeUpgrade.fetchInventoryDataTableRecords';
export default class ARADataTable extends LightningElement {
@track columns;
@track allInvTypes = [];
@track dataRecords = [];
@track pickListOptions = [];
@api options;
connectedCallback() {
   
    this.columns = [{ label: 'Inventory Type', fieldName: 'inventoryTypeCode', type: 'text', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: 'true' },
    { label: 'Priority 1', fieldName: 'p1', type: 'priorityPicklist', wrapText: true,
    typeAttributes:{
     //   options: this.pickListOptions,
       options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' },
        value :{fieldName : 'Priority'},
        placeholder: 'Choose Priority'
    }  
}
];

fetchInventoryDataTableRecords() 
    .then(result => {
       
        let options=[];
        this.dataRecords = result;
        this.defaultDataTableValues = this.dataRecords;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dataRecords.length; i++) {
            //Taking one data value of row at a time
            const item = this.dataRecords[i];
            this.allInvTypes.push(item.inventoryTypeCode);
            options.push(item.inventoryTypeCode);
        }
         this.pickListOptions.push(options);
        console.log('picklistOptions>>>>'+this.pickListOptions);
        return this.pickListOptions;
      })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });

    }
   }
```

**customPicklist.html**

```
  <template>
     <lightning-combobox
       name="picklist"
       label={typeAttributes.label}
       value={typeAttributes.value}
       placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
       options={typeAttributes.options}
       ></lightning-combobox>
  </template>
```

**customTypeGlobal.js**

```
   import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
   import customPicklist from './customPicklist.html';

   export default class CustomTypeGlobal extends LightningDatatable {
   static customTypes = {
    priorityPicklist:{
        template : customPicklist,
        standardCellLayout: true,
        typeAttributes:['label','value','placeholder','options']
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification), the options needs to be an array of label/value pairs.

e.g.

```
[{ 
    label: 'label 1',
    value: 'value 1'
},{
    label: 'label 2',
    value: 'value 2'
}]
```

Your current options appears to be just an array of strings.

Try mapping your options.

ie. instead of

```
this.pickListOptions.push(options);
```

Use

```
this.pickListOptions = options.map( element => ({ label: element, value: element }) );
```

(I haven't tested this, but you get the idea)

Comment: Hi Nick, i tried even adding mock data for testing (this.pickListOptions = [{ label: 'Test', value: 'Test' }, {label: 'Test1', value: 'Test1' }];) something like this but still its not showing. Can you help me with some more explanation.Thanks.